# How to make a clickable banner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` and there is a link inside. When I click on a div, it should open the link (ex: google.com) but when I click the button it should open another link.

```
<div class="sc-banner">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">Button</a>
</div>
```

```js
$(".sc-banner").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.open ('http://google.com', "_blank");
});
```

Comment: You've shown the click handler for the div, so what's the question?

Comment: The problem is that when I click on the button, the link (google) opens at the same time.

Comment: and how to implement correctly? so that the links work separately?

Comment: try adding click handler to the button as well with another link.

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: @A.Meshu no, that's something completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the click event from the `a` is propagating up the DOM and firing the click handler on the div.

You can fix this in a couple of ways. Firstly, check what the event target was in the `div` handler:

```
$(".sc-banner").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'A')
    window.open('http://google.com', "_blank");
});
```

Alternatively you could add another event handler to the `a` which calls `stopPropagation()`:

```
$(".sc-banner").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  window.open('http://google.com', "_blank");
});

$(".sc-banner a").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for perfect job !)